# CQL filter not quite properly formatted

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

I am trying to use the following CQL filter in Geoserver for extracting all polygons (layer1) intersecting a line (layer2):

`http://XXX.XX.X.XX:8080/geoserver/workspace/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace%3Alayer1&srs=EPSG:4326&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(geom, collectGeometries(querySingle('workspace%3Alayer2','the_geom','fid IN ('layer2.1')'))&outputFormat=application/json`

Layer 2 only has 1 feature with fid = 1, Layer 1 has hundreds of polygons.

Possibly there are other ways of retrieving the same information, but why the above is not working?

It says *Could not parse CQL filter list*

I am using Geoserver 2.15.1